# Domain transferred from Bluehost to AWS successfully but still can't call website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, bluehost

I have a website hosted on bluehost and domain for that website was also bought from bluehost. Recently I transferred that domain to aws route 53 and added aws nameserver on bluehost. It has been around 4 days. I still can't call website.

Answer (score 0):

Are you be able to ping your domain? Has it resolved to AWS IP address? Basically, DNS propagation only takes 24-48 hours.